# Can you split React Navigation TypeScript definitions across files?

Tags: typescript, react-navigation

React Navigation [documents](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#organizing-types) how to type your navigators but the definitions don't seem possible to split across files, which gets necessary as projects grow large.

The reason they seem hard to split is that the type of the parent navigator refers to the child navigator and vice versa. From the documentation above:

```js
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: NavigatorScreenParams<HomeTabParamList>;
  PostDetails: { id: string };
  NotFound: undefined;
};

export type RootStackScreenProps<T extends keyof RootStackParamList> =
  StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, T>;

export type HomeTabParamList = {
  Popular: undefined;
  Latest: undefined;
};

export type HomeTabScreenProps<T extends keyof HomeTabParamList> =
  CompositeScreenProps<
    BottomTabScreenProps<HomeTabParamList, T>,
    RootStackScreenProps<keyof RootStackParamList>
  >;
```

Note how `HomeTabScreenProps` refers to `RootStackParamList` and how `RootStackParamList` refers to `HomeTabParamList`.

How can you organize these type definitions across files?

(It is perhaps possible to move `HomeTabParamList` to its own file but `HomeTabScreenProps` doesn't seem movable without creating an import cycle.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an import cycle.

but instead I think you should organize the structure as described in the documentation

Comment: The documentation says to put it all in one file. That doesn't work well for large enough projects.